# Django Auth: Permissions for model-based category

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have Products and Companies classes in my app. Now, I'd like to have people administering products that have FK to certain company. Example:

Companies are: Foo and Bar
Products are: Apple(produced by Foo, ie. FK to it), Pear and Plum(produced by Bar)

johndoe@email.com is a user owning Foo, and janedoe@email.com is a user owning Bar. I'd like to set up privs for John to be able to add products to Foo, remove them and edit them, but only those that are related to Foo.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like django-guardian (https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian.git) for this kind of stuff. It provides object-level permissions for Django.

The way I would approach your specific problem is the following.

Define the actions that the owners of companies are allowed to complete

```
class Meta:
    permissions = [('can_add', 'Add product to company'), etc...]
```

Next I would create a group for each company on creation of a new company, by adding into the save().

```
def save():
    # Create a permission group named %s_group % company_name
    # assign(permission, group) - add the permissions to this group.
```

At this point with your example you would have Foo_group, and Bar_group, and the permissions of those objects assigned to the groups.

Now all you have left to do is add / remove users from different company groups to grant them the permissions associated with those objects.

The last component of this is checking for the permissions with the associated actions. This can be done in the appropriate views for each of the actions eg. adding, removing, etc.

I prefer class-based views because it is really nice to use Mixins for the permission checking. Guardian comes with an out of the box PermissionRequiredMixin, but usually something custom works for more complex situations.